# import date format correct in magento 2

Tags: import, date, format

i'm tring to import a date field correct into the special_from_date and special_to_date field of products however for some reason the result is not correct.

I have this

```
-<Item>
<sku>008739-91-31</sku>
<PriceChangeNo>PROM18-00011</PriceChangeNo>
<PriceType>1</PriceType>
<special_price>65.00</special_price>
<price>99.90</price>
<special_price_from_date>06-04-2018</special_price_from_date>
<special_price_to_date>09-30-2018</special_price_to_date>
</Item>
```

i try every format like d/m/y m/d/y y/m/d d-m-y m-d-y y-m-d 
but the result is everytime different date but not correct.